# swift HTTP Requests

Tags: swift, xcode, http

I have created an instant messenger chat application where by messages are posted to my server via a php service and stored in a mysql backed.

If a user has their 'inbox' page open and a new message is received I would need to update the table to show any new messages. The way I am doing this at the moment is by sending an http request to the server every 5 seconds.

As you can imagine this is pretty inefficient. What methods are available which would be more suitable and less resource heavy?

I have looked at keep alive connections and web sockets but Im not sure which direction I should be going in?

any help much appreciated!

Comment: socket programming

Comment: it's possible with silent push notification..

1/ When there is a new message, the server send silent push to iDevice.
2/ The iDevice receive silent push and refresh (or add) the new message.

Comment: amazing idea, however if the user has not permitted notifications would I implement the polling method instead? i.e. if (notificationsAllowed = false){ send a request every 5 seconds} or is there another way instead of constant polling?

Comment: Or if (notificationsAllowed = false){ show messagebox to allowed notification (with message to explain it's important for this application) ? } 

^^

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is called polling, which is not efficient because it consumes more electricity from your phone and you have extra load to your server. The correct way of doing it is though Apple's push notification. Here is the [tutorial](https://www.appcoda.com/push-notification-ios/) for that. Basically your server will send request to Apple's push notification center when a new message is received.

However in your case it's a bit more complicated. You want this notification only after user entering the mail page. So you need to tweak your php server to send notification only after user entered the mail page. In this case you are sending only one request to your server telling it to start sending notifications, instead of constantly polling your server

Comment: brilliant, would this still available to users who don't permit the notifications permission?

Comment: @MattBlack That's separate thing. If the user does not allow push notification at all, you can't do anything with it. Think about any of your app which constantly send push notification to you and you turn off the switch in setting and be a hero :)